# Increase email sending limit SMTP Go daddy

Tags: django, smtp

I have a GoDaddy workspace email which I am using in Django project using

smtp smtpout.secureserver.net

port 587

the problem is as soon as I we send more then 5 emails using smtp it gives error,"it has exceeded its 24-hour sending limit. Messages to 5 recipients out of 5 allowed have been sent. Relay quota will reset in 24 hours."

How do I increase this relay quota? I have looked in Godaddy settings, Exchange settings, mailbox settings but cannot seem to find any option

Comment: What is your actual question? The message seems pretty clear and does not have something to do with your added tags.

Comment: I have updated the question, main thing I want to ask is from where I can increase the quota? I have looked in exchange settings, mailbox settings but can't seem to find any option which says current limit is 5

Comment: I think you should look for an alternative such as SendGrid or maybe update your GoDaddy plan!

Comment: I have a good plan but I think I need to look into alternatives now,